# With Ionic and Google Maps, how do I animate map marker movement to a new location?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, ionic-framework

I have an script that first finds the user's location, then at the press of a button, places a randomly located marker within a certain distance. What I need to do next is move the randomly placed marker slowly toward the user's location. This is such a novel, useless thing, that I can't seem to find what I'm trying to do anywhere in the documentation or having been asked previously. I'd like to eventually make a total of three markers that appear when the button is pressed and move independently toward the user location at the same speed.

The existing function I've been playing with - moveMarker1 - does not do the trick.

```js
// Ionic Starter App

// angular.module is a global place for creating, registering and retrieving Angular modules
// 'starter' is the name of this angular module example (also set in a <body> attribute in index.html)
// the 2nd parameter is an array of 'requires'
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'ngCordova'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  })
})

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $stateProvider
  .state('map', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: 'templates/map.html',
    controller: 'MapCtrl'
  });

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

})

.controller('MapCtrl', function($scope, $state, $cordovaGeolocation) {
  var options = {timeout: 10000, enableHighAccuracy: true};

  $cordovaGeolocation.getCurrentPosition(options).then(function(position){
    
    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);

    var mapOptions = {
      center: latLng,
      zoom: 14,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    $scope.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

    //Wait until the map is loaded
    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce($scope.map, 'idle', function(){


      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: $scope.map,
          animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
          position: latLng
      });      

      var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          content: "Your Location"
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
          infoWindow.open($scope.map, marker);
      });

      function getRandomLoc(min, max) {
        return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
      }

      $scope.addPredators = function() {
        $scope.addPreds();
      }

      $scope.addPreds = function() {
        
        //Establish map boundaries
        var NEcornerlat = $scope.map.getBounds().getNorthEast().lat();
        var SWcornerlat = $scope.map.getBounds().getSouthWest().lat();
        var NEcornerlng = $scope.map.getBounds().getNorthEast().lng();
        var SWcornerlng = $scope.map.getBounds().getSouthWest().lng();
        
        // Create location info
        var latAdd1 = getRandomLoc(SWcornerlat, NEcornerlat);
        var lngAdd1 = getRandomLoc(SWcornerlng, NEcornerlng);
        var predLat1 = Number(latAdd1);
        var predLng1 = Number(lngAdd1);

        // Determine if predator location is too close to user
        if (Math.abs(latLng.lat() - predLat1) < 0.0075 && Math.abs(latLng.lng() - predLng1) < 0.0075) {
          console.log("too close");
          if (latLng.lat() > predLat1) {
            predLat1 = Number(predLat1) - 0.005;
          } else if (latLng.lat() < predLat1) {
            predLat1 = Number(predLat1) + 0.005;
          }
          if (latLng.lng() > predLng1) {
            predLng1 = Number(predLng1) - 0.005;
          } else if (latLng.lng() < predLng1) {
            predLng1 = Number(predLng1) + 0.005;
          }
        }

        //Place predMarker1 on map
        var predMarker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: $scope.map,
          animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(predLat1, predLng1)
        });
        
        function moveMarker1() {
          if (predMarker1.position !== latLng) {
            console.log("NOT THERE");

            // Figure out if it's above or below lat, move it
            if (predLat1 < latLng.lat()) {
              console.log("Lat is below");
              //Lat is below, move it up
              function setMarkerPosition() {
                  predMarker1.lat - 0.005;
                  predMarker1.setPosition(
                      new google.maps.LatLng(
                          predMarker1.lat,
                          predMarker1.lng)
                  );
              }
              setMarkerPosition();
              setTimeout(moveMarker1, 1000);
              map.clearOverlays(predMarker1);
            } else {
              console.log("Lat is above");
              predMarker1.lat + 0.005;
              setTimeout(moveMarker1, 5000);
            }

          }
        }

        moveMarker1();


        console.log(predLat1, predLng1);
          // setInterval($scope.placecheck, 1500);
      };

    });

  }, function(error){
    console.log("Could not get location");
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recently i encountered this issue. Main concept is so easy, its slow motion scenario, moving dots to target location slowly. Then i used this trick, i forgot link, here is my working code:

```
numDeltas: any = 100;
delay = 10; //milliseconds
i = 0;
deltaLat;
deltaLng;
moveTo(lastPositionLat, lastPositionLng) {
    if (this.lastPositionLat != undefined && this.lastPositonLng != undefined) {
        this.i = 0;
        console.log('pos lat: ' + lastPositionLat);
        console.log('pos lng: ' + lastPositionLng);
        //Calculating gap between latitudes and divide by latitude step count, calculating how much to be latitude step
        this.deltaLat = (lastPositionLat - this.lastPositionLat) / this.numDeltas;
        //Calculating gap between longitudes and divide by longitude step count, calculating how much to be longitude step
        this.deltaLng = (lastPositionLng - this.lastPositonLng) / this.numDeltas;
        console.log(this.deltaLat + ' ' + this.deltaLng);
        this.moveMarker();
    }
}

interval: any;
liveDots: any = [];
moveMarker() {
    if (this.i != this.numDeltas) {
        this.i++;

        console.log('posLat' + this.i + ': ' + this.lastPositionLat);
        console.log('posLng' + this.i + ': ' + this.lastPositonLng);
        //Moving to target latitude step by latitude step
        this.lastPositionLat += this.deltaLat;
        //Moving to target longitute step by longitude step
        this.lastPositonLng += this.deltaLng;
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(this.lastPositionLat, this.lastPositonLng);
        this.lastMarker.setPosition(latlng);
        this.map.setCenter(latlng);
        this.liveDots.push(latlng);
        this.addLine();

        let inter = setInterval(() => {
            this.moveMarker(); // Now the "this" still references the component

            if (this.i == this.numDeltas) {
                clearInterval(inter);
            }
        }, this.delay);
    }
}

//Drawing line by certain step dots
addLine() {
    var lineCoordinatesPath = new google.maps.Polyline(
        {
            path: this.liveDots,
            geodesic: true,
            strokeColor: '#007bff'
        }
    );
    lineCoordinatesPath.setMap(this.map);
}
```